# how to load packages on local computer when using remote kernels

Tags: packages, remote-access

I usually works remotely using kernels on our hpc and front-end on my local laptop. This enable me do relatively large computation within my laptop(IP address of my laptop may change frequently). But there is a problem when come across packages. Since I manage all the packages on my local computer, I can't just use `Get["mypack.m"]` when I use remote kernel, instead, I have to copy all the packages to my remote machine before `Get`. However, I'm constantly developing the packages and copying them back and forth between local and remote computer is quiet tedious. Are there simpler ways to deal with it?

Comment: Have you tried keeping your code in github/bitbucket repos and doing a `git pull` before a `Get` (on remote)?

Comment: Dropbox is also an option: [How do I put my packages into Dropbox](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34977)

Comment: if you are constantly changing your packages I fully support rm -rf suggestion to use a version control system. Using a distributed one like git or mercurial will make it especially easy to set up everything so you only need a pull + update on the remote machines before loading the packages. You don't necessarily need to resign your code to a repository hoster (or dropbox) for that if you don't want to.

Comment: @AlbertRetey It probably wouldn't be the best to simply call `git init` in the $UserBase packages directory, but I could be wrong.  I'm not certain but I'm willing to be his concern isn't the dropbox/git but correctly setting up package loading on both systems so it works.

Comment: @LiamWilliam: I agree that it isn't the best solution to use the complete `$UserBaseDirectory` as a repository, although I think it wouldn't do any harm. I also agree that the OP didn't mention to have concerns about using a repository hoster. I just wanted to make clear that rm-rf's suggestion not necessarily means that this is necessary (in case the OP or any reader would have concerns). Describing such a setup in detail is some work (and to a large extent is covered by the tools documentation) and depends on the OPs specific demands, that's probably why neither me nor anyone else did it...

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for the advice, but I'm not familiar with git, I only use Mercury as my local version control system. Also I'm worried a little bit to put my packages in dropbox, because it synchronizes to all my devices and I may accidentally ruined the sources file on my phone.

Comment: That was a fast response! :D :D In any case, bitbucket also allows mercurial repos, so you should be fine. I think bitbucket (private repo + ssh keys) should be the best option for you.

Comment: @rm-rf Sorry for the late reply, I completely forgot this post as I come across my general exam. I think the online repository is a good idea to try, but initially I was looking for something that maybe simpler, just as using the local notebook in remote kernel. How do you think `UsingFrontEnd@NotebookEvaluate["mypack.m"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this at all, but the default behavior when you [`Import` a package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Package.html) is `"Get"`. If you access your remote machine over the network, isn't an easy method to start an ftp-server on your local machine an load the packages with `Import`?

For instance it is possible to load packages directly from github (although there, you don't need to login):

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/halirutan/SymbolInformationPalette/master/SymbolInformationPalette.m"]
```

The same should be possible with ftp, `Import` and an authentication with username and password. Have you considered this option?

Comment: Thanks, yes I've considered that, but I think that maybe a little bit complicate for me. I never have any experience using a online repository. How do you think the idea in my answer?

Comment: My suggestion was not an online repository! I just gave an example that you can load a package with `Import` and you are free to use various protocols like http, ftp, sftp. I suggested to load the packages directly from your local machine but with e.g. the ftp protocol. You start your remote kernel from the local machine and the remote machine opens an ftp connection back to your local machine to load the packages.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the suggestion by rm -rf and halirutan are really great for long term development, but I guess using the online repository is kind of like over shooting the problem for me. My code are relatively small and simple and it would be tedious to push every time I made some small changes.

For my problem, I found out that I can just use the local front end to execute the package on my local computer, then somehow the package will be loaded to the remote kernel:

```
UsingFrontEnd@NotebookEvaluate["mypack.m"]
```