# How do I put my packages into Dropbox

Tags: packages, web-access

I don't want to necessarily put my packages in Mathematica's `$UserBaseDirectory`, which is on my local hard drive.  Can I somehow tell Mathematica to look for packages in other directories (like DropBox)?

Basically, I have two computers running Mathematica -- one at home, and one at work, and would like to be able to work on editing/running my packages on both computers.

Comment: Adding the path to your local dropbox folder (or subfolder where you have stored the packages) does not work? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Path.html

Comment: Ok, I tried it, and that works! but only for one time.  $Path gets reset every time I open Mathematica, so I need something more permanent.

Comment: Ok, the answer to my second question is here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/where-can-i-permanently-modify-path

Comment: @Peltio Please put your response as an answer so I can accept it.  (Please add a few words about making changes to $Path permanent).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to modify [`$Path`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Path.html) to include the directory you placed your packages into. Suppose your packages directory is in the `Dropbox\Documents\myPackages` folder inside your `home` directory; then you can add it to your path like this:

```
AppendTo[$Path, ToFileName[{$HomeDirectory, "Dropbox", "Documents", "myPackages"}]]
```

(EDIT: amended according to advice by Steve Luttrell) 
To make this change permanent, you can add this line to your [`init.m`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html) file.
Each system (home and work PC) will have a custom line of this sort in its `init.m` file that will tell *Mathematica* where to look for your packages.

Please note that since you are appending the new directory at the end of the path, system directories will have the precedence over custom ones. Just in case you decide to have the same names for different packages.
If you want your packages to have the precedence, you have to change the order your directory appears in your `$Path` either by prepending it or by placing it at a custom position.

*And now, for something extreme...*
If you really want to have *Mathematica* look elsewhere for all its files, you might want to fiddle with [`$UserBaseDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24UserBaseDirectory.html) . I have no experience with that, but the documentation says that "the value of `$UserBaseDirectory` can be specified by setting the operating system environment variable `MATHEMATICA_USERBASE` when the *Mathematica* kernel is launched. It cannot be reset from inside the kernel". I guess that by copying the actual userbase directory to your new Dropbox location and then by specifying `MATHEMATICA_USERBASE` accordingly in your OS environmental variables, you can get *Mathematica* to work directly with files in the Dropbox folder. But this is something you can do only on machines where you are an administrator, and it looks kinda risky...

Comment: Something went wrong when trying to associate links with `$namedvariables`. I had to add the links in a separate manner.

Comment: I fixed them for you. They didn't work because the markdown link syntax was incorrect. Links are entered as `[link text](url)` and `url` must have `http(s)://`

Comment: Thanks. Every day I learn something new. :-)

Comment: Because you use AppendTo rather than Append you don't need $Path =.

Comment: Right, I edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: While I agree that changeing MATHEMATICA_USERBASE is a bit extreme it might be a good solution for the OP, +1 for mentioning it. I also don't think doing that is very risky, as long as the user understands what happens. And I think your comment about environment variables is not correct. I don't know any OS where it is necessary to be administrator to set environment variables...

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to create a symbolic link if you are working on Linux or Mac OS X. I don't know how to do this in windows. In any case, for this example I put the [`MATLink`](http://matlink.org/) package in my dropbox folder. The location is the following:

```
/Users/jmlopez/dropbox/MATLink
```

To be able to use I need to put a shortcut to it

```
macbook-pro:~ jmlopez$ ln -s /Users/jmlopez/dropbox/MATLink /Users/jmlopez/Library/Mathematica/Applications/MATLink
```

Now I have two ways of accessing `MATLink`, One from the Dropbox folder and one from the hidden directory `$UserBaseDirectory`. Notice the dropbox icon.

[image: Finder Image]

I only provided this answer since I did not see anyone commenting on it. My preference would also be to modify the `Kernel/init.m` file in the `$UserBaseDirectory` as I would modify my `bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this would also serve the purpose?

```
Get[FindFile["Dropbox\\yourpackage.m"]]
```

Comment: I'm afraid you may have misunderstood `FindFile`.  `FindFile` searched for a file exactly the same way as `Get`, but instead of loading the file, it just returns the complete path.  This is useful e.g. when you need to find out which of two identically named files would be loaded by `Get`/`Needs`, or if you just need the full path for any reason.  So `Get[FindFile[something]]` will always be equivalent to `Get[something]`.  If the latter doesn't work, neither does the former.